# ArrayList<LatLng> compare to another one LatLng for distance calculation and store the result in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Now I have multiple LatLng values stored inside `ArrayList<LatLng> locations = new ArrayList<>();` and one `LatLng TGlatlng` value. I want to loop through Array and get each value of Array and compare to one `LatLng TGlatlng` to calculate distance. After that store the result in the `ArrayList<Double> distance = new ArrayList<>()`.

```
for(LatLng location : locations){
     int Radius = 6371;// radius of earth in Km
     double lat1 = location.latitude;
     double lat2 = TGlatlng.latitude;
     double lon1 = location.longitude;
     double lon2 = TGlatlng.longitude;
     double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
     double dLon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);
     double a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2)
                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
                * Math.sin(dLon / 2);
     double c = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
     double valueResult = Radius * c;
     double km = valueResult / 1;
     ArrayList<Double> distance = new ArrayList<>();
     distance.add(km); 
}
```

This is what I have done so far and I'm stuck, I don't get any value inside `ArrayList distance`, anyone have idea?

Comment: Are you sue you want to initialize `distance` in the loop, instead of outside of it? This way it can have only one value in it.\

Comment: @Shark Do you mean create a method and calling it inside the loop? I did this before but still won't works.

Comment: no Wilson, i meant something like this: `ArrayList<Double> distance = new ArrayList<>(); for (LatLng location : locations) { ..... }`

Comment: @Shark Oh, alright now I understand. My code is working now, Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The 'haversine' formula looks to be correctly implemente, not sure why distance is created inside the for loop. can you take it out and try.

Comment: Do you mean create a method and calling it inside the loop? I did this before but still won't works.

Comment: Take this outside of the loop...ArrayList<Double> distance = new ArrayList<>(); since its inside the loop its intialising everytime